# Checking if a Variable Exists in Python - Doesn't work with self

Tags: python, maya

Before you down rep this post, it hasn't been asked anywhere that I can find.

I'm checking for the existence of a list by using

```
if 'self.locList' in locals():
    print 'it exists'
```

But it doesn't work. It never thinks it exists. This must be because I'm using inheritance and the `self.` to reference it elsewhere, I don't understand what's happening.

Can anyone shed some light please?

Here is the full code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class primWingS():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def setupWing(self, *args):
        pass
    def createLocs(self, list):
        for i in range(list):
    if 'self.locList' in locals():
        print 'it exists'
            else:
                self.locList = []
            loc = cmds.spaceLocator(n = self.lName('dummyLocator' + str(i + 1) + '_LOC'))
            self.locList.append(loc)
            print self.locList


p = primWingS()
```

Comment: Can you check the indentation of your code? I think I can tell how it should be but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Why aren't you creating it inside `__init__`, rather than checking every time?

Answer (score 23):

I think you want `hasattr(self,'locList')`

Although, you're usually better off trying to use an attribute and catching the `AttributeError` which gets raised if it isn't present:

```
try:
    print self.locList
except AttributeError:
    self.locList = "Initialized value"
```

Comment: +1: For the [Python EAFP idiom](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Comment: @Johnsyweb -- yeah, from a performance standpoint, `try`-`except` will almost certainly beat `hasattr` since the docs explicitly state that `hasattr` is implemented by trying `getattr` and checking for exceptions ...

Answer (score 11):

Answering from a bit of a different perspective. `Try ... catch`, `getattr` or `dir` is the way to go if you just want the code to work.

The call `locals()` returns a dictionary of local scope. That is it includes `self`. However, you are asking for the child of `self` (`self.locList`). The child is simply not in the dictionary. The closest thing to what you are doing would be:

```
if 'locList' in dir(self):
    print 'it exists'
```

function `dir` being the generic way to query items of objects. But as noted in the other posts, it does not make much sense to query objects' attributes from a speed standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try/except or getattr with a default value, but those things don't make sense with your code. The __init__ method is there to initialize the object:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.locList = []
```

It makes no sense to allow locList not to exist. A zero length list is an object without locations.

Comment: putting it in the init doesn't work, it doesn't recognize there being a list at all

Comment: This is not correct, the init method has as the only goal to setup class attributes.

Comment: It looks like the broken indentation is not only in the pasted code. Rewrite the createLocs method with correct indentation, or python will refuse to do what you want.